# Google cloud storage function sending already delivered message when subscriber connects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a bucket in google storage cloud. Also, I have a storage function that gets triggered every time there is a new file/folder created on this bucket. The idea of this function is to publish on a google PubSub the files that were created under "monitoring" folder. So, it will get triggered once there is a new file, but only sending the message to PubSub if the file was created under the mentioned folder. Besides, I have a Java application subscribed to the PubSub receiving this messages. It is able to receive messages without issues at all, but when I shut down the application and lunch it again, after some minutes the messages that were delivered previously, are coming again. I checked the logs and see if the storage function was triggered, but it is not the case and it seems that no message was sent to PubSub again. All messages were Acked and PubSub was empty. Am I missing something related to storage function or PubSub ?

This is my storage function definition:

```js
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const topicName = 'test-topic-1';
const monitoringFolder = 'monitoring/';

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    console.log(event);
    if (isMonitoringFolder(event.name)) {
        publishEvent(event);
    }
};

const publishEvent = (event) => {
    const pubSub = new PubSub();
    const payload = {
        bucket: event.bucket,
        filePath: event.name,
        timeCreated: event.timeCreated
    };
    const data = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload));
    pubSub
        .topic(topicName)
        .publish(data)
        .then(id => console.log(`${payload.filePath} was added to pubSub with id: ${id}`))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

const isMonitoringFolder = filePath => filePath.search(monitoringFolder) != -1
```

I would really appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubsub doesn't guarantee a single occurance of the message

Google Cloud Pubsub have a At-Least-Once delivery policy. This delivers each published message at least once for every subscription. But it can be delivered multiple times

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber